# Pandas dataframe merge unsuccessful

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two pandas Dataframe with following columns:

`dataframe` 1 :

```
A, B, C
```

`dataframe` 2 :

```
A, B, C, Count
```

here is the script:

```
dfcount = pd.read_csv ( "df1.csv")
df = pd.read_csv ( "df2.csv")

df = df.dropna(axis=1,how="all")
merged = dfcount.merge(df, on=['A','B','C])
merged.to_csv("merge.csv", index=False)
```

but the merged result only contains headers name, so I have checked the file in order to find differences. The problem is that data in `dataframe` 1 are stored as follow:

```
A, B, C
Text    Active  English
```

but in `dataframe` 2 are stored like:

```
A, B, C, Count
"    Text " "    Active "   "    English "  100
```

How can I solve this conflict in two pandas `dataframe`?

Comment: Strip the spaces in both the dataframes in all columns then merge. Strip using `df[['A', 'B',' C']] = df[['A', 'B',' C']].apply(lambda x : x.str.strip())`

Comment: and replace `"` with empty char

Comment: @Bharath,@Yuan Thanks.

Comment: @Bharath: would you add an answer below, so the question author can accept it? user3806649: we have an answer acceptance system here, so we'd rather you didn't add [solved] amendments to the title. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip the spaces in the dataframe using `.str.strip`

```
dfcount[['A', 'B',' C']] = dfcount[['A', 'B',' C']].apply(lambda x : x.str.strip())
df[['A', 'B',' C']] = df[['A', 'B',' C']].apply(lambda x : x.str.strip())
```

Then you are good to merge the dataframes.

```
merged = dfcount.merge(df, on=['A','B','C])
```